# List combinations in Haskell with booleans

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, combinations, probability

So, I recently started learning Haskell and I came across a question where I need to calculate all possible outcomes(2^n) if n number of coins are flipped. For example, if 2 coins are flipped, the output should be [[H, H], [H, T], [T, H], [T, T]]. Similarly, for 3 coins it should be [[H, H, H], [H, H, T], [H, T, H], [T, H, H], [H, T, T], [T, T, H], [T, H, T], [T, T, T]]. My function does not work for arbitrary values of n. It only works if I know n from before. I'm thinking of using recursion but I'm not sure about the syntax.

This is my code:

```
outcomes(x:xs) = [[a, b] | a <- states x, b <- states (head xs)]
```

Where, the function states is:

```
states _ = [True, False]
```

This function works for n = 2. Please let me know how to make it work for any input n.

Comment: What did you try for an arbitrary number of items?

Comment: So, if I write outcomes [ H, H, H, H] it should output all the possible states, i.e 16. It should output the same if I write [H, H, T, H]. So rather than the values inside the list, the function focuses on the number of Items in the list. Therefore, if I change my function to outcomes(x:xs:xss) = [[a, b, c] | a <- states x, b <- state (xs), c <- state(xss)], it works for 3 values.

Comment: Hint: make use of recursion.

Comment: That was what I was thinking but can't seem to make it work. It's only been 3 days since I started Haskell and the syntax is quite new for me. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Well it is not entirely clear to me why you need `(x:xs)` in `outcomes`. The code you wrote can e simplified to `outcomes = [[a, b] | a <- [True, False], b <- [True, False]]` so without any parameter.

Comment: I need (x:xs) because I don't know how long the list would be. The code above will only work if 2 coins are tossed. I need to make it work for n = 3, 4, 5..... etc. (x:xs) could be used for recursion.

Comment: but that does not matter, you can work with an int. Note that you do not need to write `(x:xs)` if the head of the function if you are *returning* a list. The items in the head of the function deal with *input*, not output.

Comment: Homework assignments and exercises aside, you are computing a Cartesian product which is handled via the `[]` monad with `replicateM`. For example, `replicateM 2 ["H", "T"] == [["H","H"],["H","T"],["T","H"],["T","T"]]`.

Comment: @chepner I would say rather that the Cartesian product is handled by `sequenceA`. `replicateM`'s behavior combines Cartesian product with replicating an input N times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of recursion here. We can construct a function that takes a list of elements `[a]` and an `Int`, so:

```
outcomes :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
```

in case the integer is less than or equal to zero, then there is only one possible outcome an empty list. So we return a list that contains one empty list:

```
outcomes _ n | n <= 0 = [[]]
```

as for the recursive case, we can take an element from the list, and then recurse with the same list of values, but we create outcomes with one element less, then we prepend the element we took to these outcomes.

```
outcomes ls n = [ … | x < ls, xs <- … ]
```

here I leave the `…` parts as an exercise. In the first `…` fragment, you need to prepend `xs` with `x`. In the second one, you need to make the recursive call.

So putting this together, we implement `outcomes` as:

```
outcomes :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
outcomes _ n | n <= 0 = [[]]
outcomes ls n = [ … | x < ls, xs <- … ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want your function to work for any number of flips `n`, it should probably accept an Int parameter: how else will you get an Int? And since, as suggested in the comments, recursion is the way to do loop-like things in Haskell, you will need a base case and a recursive case. For counting things, 0 is a natural base case, and the best one to use here, but using 1 as the base case is a little easier to understand for a beginner, so we'll just let the function break for `n=0` for now.

So, you need a function with two patterns:

```
outcomes :: Int -> [[Bool]]
outcomes 1 = _
outcomes n = _
```

What should be the result for 1, i.e. one flip? Once you have that, can you implement `outcomes n` in terms of `outcomes (n - 1)`? If so, you'll be done. If not, you'll have better material for a new Question, because you'll have gotten partway to your solution.

For extra credit, once this is done, see if you can understand the recursion well enough to choose a good value for `outcomes 0` that can replace `outcomes 1` as your base case.